# Is it possible to set a background color of an element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium with Java, and I want to change a background color of an element on the screen.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it using javascript by using executescript

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('locatorid').style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';");
```

There are several javascript functions if you need to locate it by classname or name

```
document.getElementsByName
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Hope this helps you....if u need more accurate answer...pls post the element html source

Answer (score 0):

Try This

((JavascriptExecutor) WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver()).executeScript("document.querySelector("locatoe").innerText=" + value + "");

Answer (score 0):

If you have the element e.g. in Python, you can also

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';", element)
```

This probabaly works similarly in Java.