# How to modify the innerHTML of a contenteditable element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Chrome-driver and python3.6 to test a website.
I have code snippet in the webpage as follow:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="_3F6QL _2WovP">
<div class="_39LWd" style="visibility: visible;">Type a message</div>
<div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="true">*******</div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the `*******` with `Hello World!` using Selenium in the webpage. How do I do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922259/modify-innerhtml-using-selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify innerHTML using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922259/modify-innerhtml-using-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the text `*******` with the text `Hello World!` as the element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element and having the attribute **`contenteditable="true"`** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.copyable-text.selectable-text[data-tab='1']")))
  element.click()
  element.clear()
  element.send_keys("Hello World!")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'selectable-text')][contains(.,'*******')]")))
  element.click()
  element.clear()
  element.send_keys("Hello World!")
  ```
- Note: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```