# What are the best practices for using custom automation ids in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

Our web UI has unique custom automation ids for each element (buttons, labels, ...). I do not have access to normal ids of elements.

`<button custom-id='send' class='dynamic_class_123'>`

How can I access the element in a best practice manner?
Right now I use the following locator

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@custom-id='send']")
public WebElement sendButton;
```

The automation code will break once the dev is converting the button to a div element.
I would not have this problem with normal ids:

```
@FindBy(id = "send")
public WebElement sendButton;
```

It would find the element regardless of type (button, span, div, ...).

Is there a way I can achieve same result with my custom ids without the need of xpath or at least a improved version of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors without tags, here're examples:

```
css = "[custom-id='send']"
xpath = "//*[@custom-id='send']"
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- `custom-id` are analogous to [custom data attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#custom)
- Developers can configure the application to generate `custom-id` runtime.

Your code block to access the element:

```
<button custom-id='send' class='dynamic_class_123'>
```

looks perfecto as the `custom-id`s are always unique.

---

Now, the development team all of a sudden simply can't convert the `<button>` element to a `<div>` element as:

- Generally, the `<button>` elements are configured as **interactable** by default.
- Where as `<div>` elements are not **interactable** by default unless [contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914416/how-to-modify-the-innerhtml-of-a-contenteditable-element/52917565#52917565) attribute is set to **true**.

---

### Conclusion

Irrespective of the `<tagName>` in-terms of `<button>` or `<div>` or `<span>` if the application generates the unique `custom-id` for the desired elements, you can continue identifying those elements through their respective `custom-id` as follows:

- Using *css*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "[custom-id='send']")
  public WebElement sendButton;
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@custom-id='send']")
  public WebElement sendButton;
  ```