# Send keys fills form to slow (Python + Selenium) on xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `send_keys` to populate a text field in selenium. However, it takes a few seconds for the text to appear.

I would like this faster.

This is currently my xpath along with the sen_keys.

```
post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"))).send_keys(self.textContents)
```

And this is the html where i use it

```
<div data-offset-key="a467s-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="a467s-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much time does it take? Can you define `faster`?

Comment: 3 to 5 seconds for sending keys

Answer (score 0):

For [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) to traverse through the long **absolute** [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) based path may be taking some more **computing** time.

A simple solution would be to use ***relative*** xpath as follows:

```
//div[@attributeA='attributeA_value' and @attributeB='attributeB_value'][@attribute='attributeC_value']
```

---

### An Example

As an example for a `<div>` like:

```
<div class="entry" id="element_id" value="element_value"></div>
```

Your effective xpath would be:

```
//div[@class='entry' and @id='element_id'][@value='element_value']
```

Updating your code block will look like:

```
post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='entry' and @id='element_id'][@value='element_value']"))).send_keys(self.textContents)
```

Comment: How can i convert my xpath to a relative xpath based on your answer?

Comment: this is the html where i use it <div data-offset-key="a467s-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="a467s-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>

Comment: @xalom I saw your questionn edit. You are editing a `<div>`, so for a effective xpath as per the HTML you need to show us the HTML including the `<div>` which contains the attribute [contenteditable="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70822222/7429447)