# How to find the find the div element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, contenteditable, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

Selenium is unable to find an element on a webpage, here is the python code

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_13NKt copyable-text selectable-text")
```

Here is an image of the element it is supposed to find, class highlighted

[image: html code]

And here is the important line of the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._13NKt copyable-text selectable-text"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take care of a couple of things here:

- [`By.CLASS_NAME`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CLASS_NAME) accepts only one argument. So you won't be able to pass multiple classes.
- The *classnames* e.g. `_13NKt` are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in [locators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).
- The *`<div>`* is having the attribute [`contenteditable="true"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917565/7429447).

---

### Solution

To identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='pluggable-input-body'][role='textbox']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='pluggable-input-body' and @role='textbox']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The By-strategy `By.CLASS_NAME` internally uses `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and simply prefixes the locator with `.` - which is also visible in your error message

> {"method":"css selector","selector":"._13NKt copyable-text selectable-text"}

But that's not a valid CSS selector for an element that includes all those classes, instead you have to "concatenate" them with `.` (simply replace the spaces between the classes with ".")

So either:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_13NKt.copyable-text.selectable-text")
```

or use By.CSS_SELECTOR directly:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._13NKt.copyable-text.selectable-text")
```

the only difference being the leading `.`

Answer (score 1):

When using `By.CLASS_NAME` the given string is matched against each class name of you element. Your element has three different classes:

1. `_13NKt`
2. `copyable-text`
3. `selectable-text`

So the string `"_13NKt copyable-text selectable-text"` does not match any one of them.

If you really need to find the element that has all of these classes, you can use `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._13NKt.copyable-text.selectable-text")` instead (see [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors)). You may also be able to use [XPath or something else](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), if that is more up your alley.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._13NKt.copyable-text.selectable-text')))
```

You will also need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If it doesn't work, post your url.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't identify multiple class name of an element using `CLASS_NAME`, instead use `CSS_SELECTOR`.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._13NKt.copyable-text.selectable-text")
```

The `class name` can be dynamic,I would suggest use `data-testid` property.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-testid='pluggable-input-body']")
```