# How to write text into a non-input element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, contenteditable

I am trying to send automated google chats but the element of the text box in which I write the message has no `<input>` tag. The `<div>`s are not taking input. Here is the structure of the chat box:

```
<div jsname="yrriRe" jsaction="touchend:ufphYd; input:q3884e; paste:QD1hyc; drop:HZC9qb;" class="T2Ybvb KRoqRc editable" role="textbox" aria-label="History is on" aria-multiline="true" spellcheck="true" id="T2Ybvb0" g_editable="true" contenteditable="true"><br></div>
```

I tried this but is not working

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='T2Ybvb0']"))).send_keys("GOOD MORNING")
```

Comment: Are you sure it becomes "clickable"?  What happens if you just wait for some fixed period of time?

Comment: It just appears a TimeoutException

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<div jsname="yrriRe" jsaction="touchend:ufphYd; input:q3884e; paste:QD1hyc; drop:HZC9qb;" class="T2Ybvb KRoqRc editable" role="textbox" aria-label="History is on" aria-multiline="true" spellcheck="true" id="T2Ybvb0" g_editable="true" contenteditable="true">
    <br>
</div>
```

The `<div>` element is a dynamic element and contains the attribute [**`contenteditable="true"`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917565/7429447). So ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='History is on']"))).send_keys("Mike Johnes")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[aria-label='History is on']"))).send_keys("Mike Johnes")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @undetected Selenium. However they doesnt work. I have a TimeoutExpression as a result

Comment: This is EXACTLY what is original code was.  You've added nothing.  Was this answer generated by a bot?

Comment: Exactly tim, it is like he is moacking me