# How do i replace a source file or code in a js file on Selenium driver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Sorry for my bad English. I would like to edit change some code in javascript file or change the javascript file to my localhost file using Selenium . I tried to press F12 and edit .js file in source then save it when i use Chrome browser and it worked.
I wonder how to do it on Selenium web driver, i really need it for my work! Can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922259/modify-innerhtml-using-selenium

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, I can't replace a js file with javascript :((

Comment: Are you looking to change javascript function behavior which is being loaded with the page ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i'm looking for. Sorry for replying after a long time. I've been in an accident and had to be in the hospital that time :(

Comment: Not a duplicate