# VBA with SELENIUM: How to write text inside an html element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to modify all my VBA automations with selenium.
I'm trying to write text inside an html element to be able to display it on the screen.

I wish I could change this item from this:

**`<span id="__xmlview0--panel1Title-inner" dir="auto"> Ricerca </span >`**

to this:

**`<span id="__xmlview0--panel1Title-inner" dir="auto"> PIPPO </span>`**

using a Selenium command.

I tried using the command:

> DRIVER.FindElementById("__xmlview0--panel1Title-inner").SendKeys
> ("PIPPO")

but it doesn't work and returns this error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2URDZ.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Grazie

Comment: "returns the error" - what *specific* error do you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922259/modify-innerhtml-using-selenium

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I uploaded the photo

Comment: Did you try the approach shown in the link I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Sample slice code, if is a select mode:

```
        For x = 1 To 653
            If ch.IsElementPresent(FindBy.XPath("//*[@id='nl" & x & "']")) Then 'verifica se elemento x existe de fato
            ''''Debug.Print ch.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='nl" & x & "']").Text
                If (ch.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='nl" & x & "']").Text) <> "" Then 'verifica se elemento x não é vazio
                    If VBA.Trim(ch.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='nl" & x & "']").Text) = VBA.Trim(ShMacro.Range(RngSubsidaria).Value) Then
                        ch.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='nl" & x & "']").Click
                        ShMacro.Range(RngCodSubsidaria).Value = x
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next x
```

if is insert text, OK, you code is good, but i use 'FindBy.XPath' on element >inspect > rigth click > Copy > Copy Full Xpath and insert into (FindBy.XPath(" _ here your Full Xpath_ ")) where is " in xpath, change to simple ' only.

Sample my insert:

```
ch.FindElement(FindBy.XPath("//*[@id='Transaction_TRANDATEfrom']")).SendKeys ShMacro.Range(RngDataDe).Value
```

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for the reply. I tried your solution with XPath but it doesn't work

Comment: Try no use () after sendkey comando use only sendkey "PIPPO"