# vba selenium how to add an element to an element?

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Excel VBA with Selenium and I need to modify a web page.

Reason is that I did not find the way to input some data in a field in a web page but found out how the data looks like once entered. It adds a li element in a ul list.

Question is: how can I create a li element under the ul element of the web page?

Thank you

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926114/478884

Comment: This sounds like you are doing something wrong. Have a look at [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and please provide some additional context.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your comments, I understand that the solution I was trying to build goes into a wrong direction. I'll change my mind...